# pass value to the server

Tags: java

How do I modify this code and pass msg string value to the server? I don't want it to print any character on the console. On my server, I receive a Null value.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SocketClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a socket without a timeout

String msg = "sssssssssssssssssssssss";
    try {
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
        int port = 8090;

        Socket socket = new Socket(addr, port);
        //ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedWriter oos = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        System.out.println("qqqqqqqq");
        oos.write(msg);
        oos.flush();

        oos.close();


    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should also post the code for your server.

Comment: I using the server is xSocket

Comment: perhap you still avail to see my server code?

Comment: Yeah.  Having something we can compile and test would be helpful.

Comment: http://giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=205 I able to create Flex to connect to xSocket server but there is no info on creating a Java client

Comment: Hope there is a solution as I been google for the past 2 days without an answers.

Comment: Hello, is anyone there to testing out?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, your code looks correct. However, be sure to print exceptions when you catch them. Otherwise, you'll never know if you've done something wrong.

Comment: You mean the ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()) can be use in this scenario without user input or println?

Answer (score 0):

If your servers code is `String data = nbc.readStringByDelimiter("\0");` you need to send 0 byte after the message: `socket.getOutputStream().write(0);`

Comment: @user217582 What do you mean?

Comment: I add the code .write(0) it throw an error "void type not allow here"

Comment: @user217582 Sorry, I didn't get nor your question neither your comment. I don't have any code. What I wanted to say: you provided a link to look at the server-side code. I found there the line I posted in my answer, that was: `String data = nbc.readStringByDelimiter("\0");`. Question: do you have the server-side code that reads the messages you send? Where do you get null?